# How to get related rows from attributes table assigned to a certain attribute in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have category table, attribute table and attribute_value table,

```
Category:
id | Catgeory Name 

Attribute:
id| cat_id | Attribute Name

Attribute values Table:
id | attr_id | attr_value
```

Now i want to Display it like this :

```
Category Name 
Attribute Name 1
Attribute Val 1
Attribute val n
Attribute Name 2
Attribute Val 1
Attribute Val n
..
..
```

I'm using  following model

> Attribute:

```
 public function attr_values()
  {
  return $this->hasMany(AttributeValue::class);
  }
```

Category:

```
public function categoryAttributes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Attribute::class, 'category_id');
    }
```

In controller i'm getting data using following:

```
  Category::with(['categoryAttributes','attrValues'])->get()->find($categoryId);
```

But i'm unable to get the data attributes that are linked to Category and its attributes Values.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Do you have a  `hasMany` relationship between Category & Attribute Models?

Comment: @Makdous: i have  edited my code above. Please check, now i am getting categories attributes but not getting category attribute values.

Comment: try `Category::where('$categoryId',1)->with(['categoryAttributes.attrValues'])->first();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can join your tables and select the columns you want:

```
 Category::whereIn('id', $ids)->join('attribute', 'attribute.cat_id', '=', 'category.id')
            ->join('attribute_value', 'attribute_value.attr_id', '=', 'attribute.id')
            ->select('category.category_name', 'attribute.attribute_name', 'attribute_value.attr_value')->get();
```

using relations:

```
  Category:: with(['categoryAttributes'=>function($query){
            $query->addSelect('attribute.cat_id','attribute.attribute_name')
                ->with(['attr_values'=>function($query){
                    $query->addSelect('attribute_value.attr_value','attribute.attr_id');
            }]);
        }])->whereIn('id', $ids)->get();
```

please note that adding foreign key relation column to select statement is necessary so laravel get the right object

Comment: Thanks OMR but i want it with relation

Comment: It is fetching data till attributes but attribute values is blank

Comment: try load all the attribute values without add select

Comment: how will i retrieve it on my view , i'm using this loop @foreach($category as $cat) but no data is retrieved but in $category there is data, screenshot added in question,

Comment: @foreach($category as $cat) {@foreach($cat->categoryAttributes as $attt){@foreach($attt->attr_values as $attr_value)}}